# CSS Items below Float:Left not working

Tags: css, html, css-float

Using "float:left;" to place divs side-by-side is causing issues. I can't seem to place another div directly below the floating divs.

See JSFiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/8RgkE/

You can see that the GREEN box rests Underneath the RED and BLUE boxes, but I need the green box to shift down BELOW the two boxes. I can't seem to do this and keep "float:left" boxes.

**Here's the kicker:** The **height** of the red and blue boxes may be subject to change, so you cannot encapsulate the small boxes into a div and size that div.

HTML

```
<div id='red' class='box'></div>
<div id='blue' class='box'></div>
<div id='green'></div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  float:left;
}

#red {background-color:red;}

#blue {background-color:blue;}

#green{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background-color:green;
  border:4px solid black;
}
```

Comment: boo on floats! if you want to enter the development era post-2001, learn to use `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear the floats.

```
#green{
    clear: both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8RgkE/2/

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `clear: left;` on `#green`

http://jsfiddle.net/8RgkE/1/

Comment: Thank you, but James beat you to it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the divs to start a new line.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/8RgkE/3/

I normally use a clearing `div` like so

`<div style="clear: both"></div>`

Another solution would be to replace `float: left` with `display: inline-block`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/8RgkE/4/

Answer (score 0):

the safest & most extendable way is to add a new element with `clear:both;` before green div.

HTML

```
<div id='red' class='box'></div>
<div id='blue' class='box'></div>
<div id='clear'></div>
<div id='green'></div>
```

CSS

```
#clear{
  clear:both;
}
```